# AJAX Complete Handler in Pure JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using AJAX in pure Javascript which returns `false` if failed else returns a `json` data:

```
    var responsefromURL = loadAjaX(url);
    if(responsefromURL != false)
    {
        alert("Failed to fetch Data from URL. (Store/Store)");
    }
    else
    {
        this.prepareStoreFromJSON(responsefromURL);
    }
```

Since Javascript is async, `responseFromURL` is not loaded ASAP. In jQuery, I could use `ajax.complete` protocol. How do I do that in pure Javascript? **I want to load AJAX from a different function because I have a lot of methods which implement this, so cannot type the same AJAX Code over and over again.**

> In response to comment from Banana,

We could do:

```
 ajax.open("GET",url,false);
```

> But, most browsers have this feature disabled and throw error : Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: setting false as the 3rd parameter of `XMLHttpRequest.open()` method makes the call synchronous.

Comment: @Banana, that's makes sense but most browsers have this feature disabled and throw error : `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: The error makes sense too, after all your website will hang until the ajax returns. You can however, put this in a function and call it from a `setTimeout()`, it wil run thw whole thing on a new thread.

Comment: @Banana Timers from `setTimeout()` don't run in a separate thread, they just run on the next event loop tick after the timeout is up. ([More details here.](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)) To my knowledge, the only way to run JS in a separate execution context is web workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume this is your AJAX function:

```
function loadAjaX(url, callback)
{
    var ajax;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {
            callback(ajax.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajax.open("GET",url,true);
    ajax.send();
}
```

Now you can call your callback method with the `response` on complete:

```
loadAjaX(url, callback);
```

Comment: What if I want to call with multiple parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var responsefromURL = xmlhttp.responseText;
    if(responsefromURL != false)
    {
        alert("Failed to fetch Data from URL. (Store/Store)");
    }
    else
    {
var responseJSON = eval('('+responsefromURL+')');        
this.prepareStoreFromJSON(responseJSON);
    }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Well, that is an around solution which I also figured out. But I have an organized Class and want to call the AJAX method at a different point. I was looking for something like `on complete`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a function on the onreadystatechange property.

see documentation http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

example

```
var COMPLETE = 4;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

    // if complete and status 200
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == COMPLETE && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if (xmlhttp.responseText != null) {
            prepareStoreFromJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        else {
            alert("Failed to fetch Data from URL. (Store/Store)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that is an around solution which I also figured out. But I have an organized Class and want to call the AJAX method at a different point. I was looking for something like `on complete`.