# ajaxComplete in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension using Content Script.

I have a piece of code that injects DOM elements upon success of all ajax request on the page using jQuery. How can you recreate this without jQuery?
Please note that I cannot modify any ajax requests on the page.

```
if(window.jQuery){
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    for(var i =0; i< $jq('div.handwave').length; i++){
        if($($('div.handwave')[i]).children('.done').length < 1){
            $(document).find('div.handwave').eq(i).append(wind);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: To be clear-- jQuery is just a library written in JavaScript-- anything possible with jQuery is possible with JavaScript because under the hood it _is_ JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery is just an extension of JavaScript. There is nothing jQuery provides that raw JavaScript can't handle. Visit [**You Might Not Need jQuery**](http://www.youmightnotneedjquery.com) and decode your script piece by piece.

Comment: I don't get any alternatives for ajaxComplete unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX Complete Handler in Pure JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427189/ajax-complete-handler-in-pure-js)

Comment: @HemantPawar it is not, because I do not have control over modifying ajax request creation.

Comment: Yes you do. Simply use XMLHttpRequest **instead**.

Comment: @ObsidianAge how? any example? I unfortunately do not have leverage to modify the ajax request itself. All I was able to do is listen in all successful ajax responses (using jq, which I would like to avoid).

Comment: if you want to duplicate this jQuery functionality, you'll need to rewrite all your (presumably) XHR requests to call some function on "loadend"

Comment: How about a simple function to check if the expected output of the AJAX function exists, and loop it if not (until the output is found)?

Comment: `I was able to do is listen in all successful ajax responses` - No, you're able to listen to all *jquery successful responses*, not *all ajax responses*, because AJAX is not just a jquery concept - i.e if some code uses XMLHttpRequest or fetch, then jQuery has no knowledge of it ... so, if all your AJAX is written in jQuery, you already need jQuery, so use jQuery

Comment: @xoail you may want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @JaromandaX That makes sense. Just to confirm, I cannot use pure js to recreate ajaxComplete unless I modify the ajax request to use XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I wasn't saying that @xoail - but when you buy a car do you need to invent the wheel? what is wrong with using one jQuery method, when you already need to use other jQuery methods

Comment: You could try overriding the `XmlHttpRequest.prototype.send` method that can add an event listener for the `load` event before calling the original `send`. Note that this would not cover the `fetch` API

Comment: @JaromandaX its a chrome extension and I want to avoid loading jquery.

Comment: @Phil any example you can you point me to?

Comment: @xoail - in an extension you have powerful tools for intercepting requests/responses

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update

If you're writing a Chrome extension, you should probably use the `chrome.webRequest` API. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

---

You can override one of the existing methods required to make an AJAX request such as `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` to add your own *load* event listener. For example

```
(function() {
    const send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() { 
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            console.log('global handler', this.responseText)
            // add your global handler here
        })
        return send.apply(this, arguments)
    }
})()
```

As mentioned in the comments, this won't cover the `fetch` API.

Comment: Note: This will result in your `load` handler being called *after* any `load`, and, I assume, `readystate`, handlers which the page has already added. For this question, it doesn't appear that matters, but it will in some other circumstances. If you desire to be sure your handlers are called first, you would need to override the `XMLHttpRequest` constructor.