# Differentiate webRequest.onBeforeRequest original page vs. injected

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm using `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` in the background script. Then, in the content(?) script, that is *injected* to the original page I make an AJAX request to the same URL to which the page makes the request I'm detecting, so naturally it starts to loop which hangs the browser pretty soon!

As a temporary measure, I put another parameter at the end of the URL in my AJAX call (&me=1) and made a `urls` filter that ends like the original URL ends, but that doesn't seem the best way, since the original URL might change in the future.

What would be better way of doing it? For example, I looked at the `requestDetails` that my listener returned. But, since the script is injected in the original page, I can't find any difference. Or, maybe I could make a `urls` filter which would only accept URLs that *don't* end with "&me=1"...?

(I can't (won't) use a flag variable, because the page changes dynamically and again, it doesn't seem the best way, even if I could make it work somehow (I haven't).)

Of course, alternatively, I could just use the data that the original request provides, but I could not [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) the event/object that would do it, but maybe I've missed it somehow, since I'm pretty much a beginner in making web extensions.

Edit:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "testtube",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "https://*/*",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "https://www.youtube.com/player_api",
    "index.html",
    "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
    "js/player.js",
    "js/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "css/jquery-ui.css", "css/style.css"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "https://www.youtube.com/watch*"],
      "css": [ "css/jquery.dataTables.min.css", "css/jquery-ui.css", "css/style.css" ],
      "js": [ "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js","js/jquery-ui.min.js",  "js/main.js" ]
    }
  ]
  ,"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js" ]
  }

}
```

background.js

```
"use strict";

var lastRequestId = 0;

function logURL(requestDetails) {

    console.log("requestDetails: ", requestDetails);
//this is actually a solution as per my answer below
    if ((lastRequestId != requestDetails.requestId) && (requestDetails.url.indexOf("&me=1") == -1))
    {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(requestDetails.tabId, { ccurl: requestDetails.url }).then(response => {
            console.log("Message from the content script:");
            console.log(response.response);
        }).catch(onError);;

    }
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(logURL);
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  logURL,
  { urls: ["*://www.youtube.com/api/somepattern*"] }
);

function onError(error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
}
```

main.js

```
"use strict";
var jq;

jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.onload = function () { };
jq.src = chrome.extension.getURL("/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js");
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(jq);

jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.onload = function () { };
jq.src = chrome.extension.getURL("/js/jquery-ui.min.js");
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(jq);

/*... some other scripts... */

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('/js/player.js');
s.onload = function () {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

var _url = "";


function UURL(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    _url = request.url;

    var loadR = " loadRequest('" + _url.toString() + "'); ";

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = loadR;

    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);

    return Promise.resolve({ response: "Hi from content script" });
}


$(function () {

    console.log("jquery loaded");

    browser.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(UURL)
    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(UURL);

    /* irrelevant code here... */

});
```

player.js

```
var loadRequest = function loadRequest(_url) {
_url = _url + "&me=1";

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: _url,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        /* irrelevant code here */
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I usually try to provide some code but in this case I felt the question is more of a conceptual one.. I tried my best to describe it though. I don't feel it's the "why isn't this code working the way I want" type of question, is it? Sorry, if it clogs SO, then just delete it since I think I have a working answer.. thanks for the patience.

Comment: That does not mean you won't get other answers which might be useful to you, or that the question & answers won't be useful to other people. However, yes, to me it reads as a question where you have code what isn't doing what you desire. Even if this was just a conceptual question, you have code that doesn't do what you want. That code helps to narrow/define the question. Why would you *not* want the code included in the question if it helps focus people's answers on the exact issue you are having?

Comment: Because I thought I described it sufficiently enough, because I'd have to basically write a new, clean and obfuscated code - and so people couldn't test it anyway. It's too specific. Yes, I'm paranoid a little..

Comment: Further, you explicitly state that you are open to other options, including using the data returned from the original request, which is certainly possible. I do similar things in scripts. There are various questions on the subject, including at least one recent one (I'm looking for it). However, what options to suggest depend largely on what the page is doing, what you are currently doing, and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: For example, some other options off the top of my head, might be to perform the request from the background script, a different frame, or different tab. Personally, assuming that I actually needed the information in the content script, I'd probably listen in to the response obtained by the webpage from its request, as that is easy to do and doesn't result in duplicating the request (which might be detected by the server).

Comment: I will try to provide some code later, I have to sleep now.

Comment: The recent question I mentioned: [ajaxComplete in pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45340281). The answer should give you some information as to how you might listen in to the request made by the page.

Comment: @Makyen I provided some code. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

### If you are attempting to differentiate between the main page load and your `XMLHttpRequest`<sup>1</sup>

There are multiple ways that you could differentiate between different types of requests. Without your actual code to try it out, we have to guess as to what you are actually doing.

The [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) for a normal page load will look like:

```
webRequest.onBeforeRequest ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"260870","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401223979.044,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you can see, the [`details`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest#details) Object contains a `type` property, which is a [`webRequest.ResourceType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/ResourceType). For the load of HTML for the main frame it will contain `"main_frame"` (the `details` Object will also have `"frameId":0,"parentFrameId":-1`).

For your AJAX request, the value of the `type` property should be `xmlhttprequest`. However, it's possible that by "ajax request" you meant something other than an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). In which case, the `type` property might have some other value, but it should not be `"main_frame"`.

---

1. I read the original version of the question differently than okkko intended. As currently written, this does not cover the case which they are interested in. However, it might have some value to someone else reading this question/answer, so I'm leaving it up.

Comment: No, as I said, I did not find any difference between the requests. In my case `type` is always `xmlhttprequest`. Same goes for all other properties (except for `timeStamp˙).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the improved version of "temporary measure" is that in the listener I add another condition against requested url

```
(requestDetails.url.indexOf("&me=1") == -1)
```

And *then* make my ajax call... and in the `urls` filter for the request I just leave asterix (*) at the end. In this way, it doesn't matter if the original url changes at the end, however technically additional request is caught.. good enough if nobody else replies.